# how to modify HttpRequest QueryString value in class library?

Tags: c#, query-string, httprequest

how to modify HttpRequest QueryString value in class library,i current can get QueryString value and modify,but how to write the modified QueryString to HttpRequest:

```
public static HttpRequest ModiQueryString(HttpRequest request)
{
    var nv = new NameValueCollection(request.QueryString);
    foreach (string key in nv.Keys)
    {
        nv[key] = "abc";
    }
    //here how to let request.QueryString equal nv
    return request;
}
```

because the request.QueryString is read-only,so how can i do?
who can help me?thanks

if i create a new HttpRequest,is i can use:

```
StringBuilder newQuery=new StringBuilder();
foreach(string key in nv.Keys)
{
    newQuery.AppendFormat("{0}={1}",key,FilterKeyWord(nv[key]));
}
HttpRequest newRequest = new HttpRequest("", request.Url, newQuery.ToString());
return newRequest;
```

Comment: Why do you want to, why do you need to modify the query string?

Comment: i want create a common service to filter keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply impossible because [`QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) is not settable and the class is `sealed` to boot.

You should either modify the query string before the request is constructed, or if you only have an `HttpRequest` to work with then keep a temporary copy of the query string (which you can edit) and construct another `HttpRequest` with the modified query string.